# Autoscroll won't scroll to element, broken JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button which is supposed to scroll down to another element but on a fallback (JS not working for e.g.) go to the contact us page.

The code itself is not working, it won't even log to console. Any fixes?

```
    $('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("test");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($('.contactSplit').offset().top)
    }, 500);
})


<a class="btn btn--primary" href="https://hannahlondon.com/contact-us/">SPEAK TO ONE OF OUR EXPERTS</a>
```

Comment: is this code inside a $(document).ready() handler? Also remove the space between function and (e)

Comment: Any errors in the console? I tried your code here in the snippet and it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks to work as long as you also have an element with the `contactSplit` class. See this snippet:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("test");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($('.contactSplit').offset().top + 20)
    }, 500);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn--primary" href="">SPEAK TO ONE OF OUR EXPERTS</a>
<div style="height:500px">Content</div>
<div class="contactSplit">Contact Us</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Try "Hard refreshing" with `Shift + F5` on Windows / `Shift + CMD + R` on MacOS

Comment: Just triple checked, the code for the contactSplit is
<section class="contactSplit greyBg>, And JQuery is loaded, my whole site runs off JQuery. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is your console tossing any errors? Also, you aren't using the `btn` class anywhere else are you?

Comment: none at all, check my site for reference, it is the SPEAK TO ONE OF OUR EXPERTS button
https://hannahlondon.com/hairdressing-and-colouring/

Comment: The site works, you might have a bad cache. Try "Hard refreshing" with `Shift + F5` / `Shift + CMD + R`